# How to convert cgm to png on windows

Tags: png, cgm

I want to convert a .cgm file to an image file (.png) on windows.

Are there any freeware/opensource tools for this? I tried to ImageMagik but it does not support this operation. Commandline inteface will be an added advance if any of the tools provide it.

Answer (score 1):

[UniConvertor](https://sk1project.net/uc2/) is open source, and the best choice in my opinion.

The windows binaries worked great for me, https://sk1project.net/uc2/download/

From a command line you'd simply type `uniconvertor input.cgm output.png`

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://cortona3d.com/en/cortona2d-viewer-download. When installed it understand .cgm extension and directly opens in IE and you can view it/or take snapshot.

Other tool that you can try(but not free) is reaConverter(https://www.reaconverter.com/)
It has a nice command line interface that converts cgm to PNG directly

Comment: Huh, i was looking for some opensource/Freeware. I tried cortona2d-viewer It works fine. reaConverter requires license so i am avoiding it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free tool available [XnView](https://www.xnview.com/en/) which is very handy when it comes to view, resize and edit your images. It supports more than 500 different formats. But you will have to download an additional plug-in https://www.cadsofttools.com/products/plugins-for-3d-party-programs/ It will enable your need to deal with CGM file formats.